# Msbuild 14.0 x64 can't run custom task

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I wrote a custom msbuild task and compiled it with MSBuild 14.0 x64.
Wrote msbuild scenario for use this task and try to run it with the same msbuild 14.0 x64. But it fails with error:

```
build.proj(90,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'RefForTask, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

RefForTask is dependency for my CustomTask.dll

But if I run my scenario with MSBuild 14.0 x86 it works correctly!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use process monitor to find where the dll is being searched for and manually place it there? It may be gross but it's a good first troubleshooting step